# Segmentation fault 11 in Swift 3/Xcode 8.2/Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have done all the steps offered in other solutions (clean, update cocoadpods, restart XCODE) but I still have a Segmentation Fault 11 preventing my project from running BUT with the twist that it happens randomly.

The issue started after I installed Firebase in my project and started setting rules and code to retrieve/write data that involves a lot of functions with if/else statements.

The problems are:

1. The problem happens randomly, i.e. if i restart Xcode and re-run, clean, it will sometimes run, sometimes not. and
2. the debugging info is completely incomprehensible to me (I'm a newbie, but there's not even 1 line that is something meaningful in the debugger).

I've read in other solutions that if you pay attention to the debugger you could figure out where the issue comes from, could someone though explain which part of the debugger exactly? As in my case it really is all completely incomprehensible information.

So the question is, is there any step by step process I should follow, or something in the debugger I should pay attention to, as a rule, for when Segmentation fault 11 occurs? Given my problem that it will run randomly some times, and others it will not? (obv without changing anything in the project). Many thanks.

Comment: You should isolate the code that is causing the crash and post it. You may also have an issue trying to use Firebase synchronously and variables or other data may be out of scope when you try to access it.

Comment: The problem is the problem started appearing after about 900 lines of code and already a lot of interacting between code and Firebase. Half way through it started happening rarely, i just hit run again and it would compile. Now happening almost half the times I press "run". Project so big now I can't isolate a snippet thats relevant. How would I go about identifying if the out-of-scope issue is at fault? Thx for your reply

Comment: Add breaks to your code. Run the code to the first break. If it works, then continue to second break. Rinse, repeat until it blows up then you will know which breaks the error is between.

Comment: My issue is though that the error happens completely randomly (ie it might show up on 2 consecutive "run" attempts, then work on the 3rd without any changes). Which means I would have to repeat each step multiple times to make sure it s not gonna crash (and still I wouldnt be sure given the randomness of the runs in which the error appears)..Guess I 'll have to try your advise with a lot of patience. Oh dear. Thanks again